# Security of time server based validation code

Tags: android, unit-testing, security, android-security

I am developing an **Android application** for which I am checking **application's validity** (whether application is running after free trial period) using **time servers**.

My application's code checks, whether **current date is less then certain date dd/MM/YYYY**. My code retrieves current date from some popular **time server**.

I have following questions:

1. What are possible **logical security threats** to my code? i.e. what possible hacks can be done to have unlimited free trial?
2. How can I **improve the security of my application** to avoid hacks related to validation process?
3. How can I **unit test** this part of the code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. An attacker can modify the apk and change the end of time trial date or remove the whole check. This is relatively easy, depending on where you store it, they may need to decompile the source, but that's also fairly easy.
2. Technically, you can obfuscate your code to make decompilation harder, but on the one hand, it only helps if your end of trial date is hard-coded (compiled into the source), and on the other hand an attacker can still change it (or remove the whole check) with a bit more work. It would need a slightly more determined and/or more resourceful attacker though, if it is obfuscated. As it is impossible to fully prevent this (an attacker will always be able to use your app for as long as they want, see all the pirated software before the SaaS era), you may not want to do any more than this. The work needed increases very quickly on your end, but the benefit (security) you get does not.
3. This is probably a completely separate question, maybe you should post it separately. My (maybe naive) take is that you should mock the part that sends out the request to the time server, but I'm no expert in this.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful information @lengyelg. Do you have any recommendations about which forums will be appropriate to post such type of questions?

Comment: I think you can post them on StackOverflow, specific, answerable, programming related questions are good here.